Comparing PCA Methods: Constraining to 3 Components vs Using the First 3 Components from a Full Model
Hello Stats Community!
I'm exploring Principal Component Analysis (PCA) for a project and I'm curious about the practical differences and implications of two PCA approaches:
Directly constraining the PCA model to 3 components.
Running PCA with all components and then selecting the first 3 components.
Specifically, I'd like to understand:
How might the choice between these methods affect the interpretation of the data?
Are there scenarios where one method is definitively preferable over the other?
The goal is to make component scores and then use them as IVs.
Any insights, references, or examples on how these two approaches might differ in application and outcome would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
